# Retrieve epay.info Balance with VBA and Excel

Tags: vba, excel, bitcoin

The site in question got a login form before accessing data, and it don't furnish any API's.
Some idea or suggestion?
Here is an extract of code of the login page (http://epay.info/Login/):

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="form-signin" action="" method="post" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">ePay.info Login</h2>
    <div class="login-wrap">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input style="margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Wallet addresses, Username or E-mail address" class="form-control input-lg" type="text"><img title="Lunghezza massima del campo sconosciuta" style="position: relative; left: 304px; top: -33px; z-index: 999; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: bottom; border: 0px none; width: 14px; height: 19px; display: inline;" class="ife_marker" src="chrome://informenter/skin/marker.png" id="username_ife_marker_0">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input style="margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password (only if secured)" class="form-control input-lg" type="password"><img title="Lunghezza massima del campo sconosciuta" style="position: relative; left: 304px; top: -33px; z-index: 999; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: bottom; border: 0px none; width: 14px; height: 19px; display: inline;" class="ife_marker" src="chrome://informenter/skin/marker.png" id="password_ife_marker_1">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" name="login" type="submit">Login and check stats</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should log you in, provided you enter the correct values for these two lines:

```
username.Value = "Test"
password.Value = "Test"
```

Open the VB Editor by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and insert a new standard code module.  Paste in the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub LoginToEpay()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim username As Object
    Dim password As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True

    'Navigate to the website
    IE.navigate URL:="http://epay.info/Login/"

    'Wait for page to load
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    'Username and password elements have IDs
    Set username = IE.document.getElementById("username")
    Set password = IE.document.getElementById("password")

    'Login button doesn't have an ID so we must use name
    'This returns an array of items that have the name
    'login
    Set loginBtn = IE.document.getElementsByName("login")

    username.Value = "Test"
    password.Value = "Test"

    While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" Then objCollection(i).Click
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Hopefully most of it is self-explanatory.  The most confusing part is the `getElementById` versus `getElementsByName`.  The first one returns a single element based on the id in the HTML while the second one returns an array of objects that contain whatever name you pass in.  I can use `getElementById` because there are ids supplied for the username and password fields.

There is not an id provided for the login button, so to get that button I had to return an array of all objects with the name "login" (in this particular example, there was only one).  I then cycle through all of the buttons in the `While..Wend` loop and press the one that says submit.

I could have not included the `While..Wend` loop and simply said:

```
objCollection(0).Click
```

But I thought it would be in your best interest to see a better practice.

This will at least get you logged in.

Comment: I modify your code because here - 'Wait for page to load
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop - enter in a never-ending loop :-)  then, in the second istance of the While...Wend vba stops and say me: "Error run-time '70': No Authorization (because the log-in has been done!), so i use this code: If objCollection(0).Type = "submit" Then objCollection(0).Click